# How to make a Create method which creates new user account and Login method if the account was already created in C#

Tags: c#, database, methods, entity-framework-core

I'm a student in a C# course for coding advanced business applications. I've been assigned this task and am completely stumped on how to code the first part of the assignment. This is the official assignment prompt and Task #1 that has had me googling and stuck for days:

"Create a Stack Overflow like app that will keep track of users’ questions and answers. Each user will have a first name, last name, e-mail address, and registration date/time. Each question includes a question text and date/time posted. Each answer should have an answer text and date/time posted.

1. Log In. When your app first starts, ask the user for their email address. If it is already in the database, log the user in automatically, otherwise create a new user account for them. You don't need to deal with passwords, just check the email address.

Again, Task #1 has me stumped. Any help out there? Even just some hints in the right direction/or knowledge bases would be much appreciated!! Thank you in advance!

Comment: See codeproject : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/739164/Entity-Framework-Tutorial-for-Beginners

Comment: Thank you for this...I will look it over. I think I def have the meat and potatoes of the EF Core down. One of our tutors helped another student my helping them make a Create Method and a Login Method. I've already reached out to that tutor for help, but was hoping that someone here had some helpful info as well. Thank you again!